# Javascript open source mobile game engine with Audio and Particles?

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine

I have managed to find lot's of great graphics engines out there, such as Kinetic and Fabric, but none of them have Audio or Particles support, like a real game engine. I also found Starling, but it's not public yet. Anyone recommends a good open-source engine for mobile Javascript games?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend http://threejs.org/ but then again, if you are thinking about making games for mobile you might think about looking in to unity3d or unreal.